# filter_input on a int form field

Tags: php, filter

How can I filter, using `filter_input`, a `$_POST` or `$_GET` variable as INT if the HTML form always send "string" data type?

For example try to validate a month number

```
$options = array( 'options'=>[ 'min_range'=>1, 'max_range'=>12 ] );
return
 ( !empty( $_POST[$month] ) )
 ? filter_input( INPUT_POST, $month, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options )
 : TRUE;
```

the form field:

```
<label>Month<select name="month" id="month" size="2"><option></option>
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
<option value="07">07</option>
<option value="08">08</option>
<option value="09">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
</select>
</label>
```

Comment: Your problem is the leading zeros. `01` through `09` are not valid integers.

Comment: ok, but I can't handle it for example using typecast (int).. and using 1,2,3,4.. is not user friendly

Comment: Just change the values, users will only see the text (eg. `<option value="1">01</option>`)

Comment: If leading zeroes are relevant, you don't have a number. If they aren't relevant, you shouldn't add them.